# Why in Java incompatibility of types to casting is checked at runtime and type mismatch to converting at compile time?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, runtimeexception

Let's say there are 2 classes. And `Child` extends `Parent`.

```
public class Parent {}
```

and

```
public class Child extends Parent {}
```

I know that the following code is incorrect:

```
Child obj = new Parent(); // causes java.lang.Error
```

or

```
Child obj = (Child) new Parent(); // causes java.lang.ClassCastException
```

But I don't understand why I get a *compile error* in the first case and *runtime exception* in the second case. After all, a parent can never be convert or cast to child. **Why second of these cases is not checked at compile time?**

I would be very grateful for a clear and reasonable idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Child obj = new Parent();
```

In this case the compiler tries to check (implicit cast) if `Parent` object can be set to `Child` reference and when this casting fails, you get compile time error.

```
Child obj = (Child) new Parent();
```

In this case the compiler sees that you are explicitly casting `Parent` object to `Child`, so compiler leaves it for the runtime to decide if the casting is valid, in a sense the developer takes the responsibility of the casting. So if this casting fails, you get a runtime error.

Comment: but why to get casting exception in second case.It seems to be fine.I tried and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

> Child obj = new Parent(); // causes java.lang.Error

No it doesn't. It causes a compilation error. Not the same thing at all. Don't confuse yourself by equating things that are distinct.

The compiler checks as much as it possibly can, and leaves the rest to runtime. In this case the assignment to Child is obviously incorrect and can be detected at compile time. The other case cannot be detected at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, you use explicit casting.  That means basically you are telling the compiler you know what is going to happen.  It's a way to tell the compiler what the type is, so he believes you.

The runtime however has to do the job...  He cannot, so he's the one rightfully complaining.

(he / she?..)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that it would take extra work for the compiler to detect this case, and it couldn't get it right in all cases. It's not worth the extra work to make this a compiler error sometimes but not all the time.

While an *instance* of Parent can never be a Child, a *reference* to Parent might actually point to a Child. In general, if you cast an *expression* of type Parent to Child, it *might* succeed. To identify that it can't the compiler must know extra information about the expression of type Parent. In this case, it's a constructor invocation. That's the simplest possible case, and pretty much the only scenario in which it's *obvious* that an expression of type Parent cannot refer to an instance of type Child. It's not really worth adding that extra complexity to the compiler for such minimal benefit.